# Google maps activity crashes after successful installation

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Not sure why this is happening, the application shows no errors and I've obtained the key successfully as well but the activity doesn't run!

Here is my MapScreen class:

```
            package com.example.prateekchachra.projectconnecttoastmasters;        

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.os.PersistableBundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;        

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;        

    /**
     * Created by Prateek Chachra on 5/23/2016.
     */
    public class MapScreen extends Activity{
        static final LatLng Pos = new LatLng(40, -79);
        private GoogleMap googleMap;        


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            try {
                if (googleMap == null) {        

                    googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                }
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);        

                Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Pos).title("That is my loc"));        

        } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        }        



    }
```

Here is my activity_maps.xml file:

```
            <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.prateekchachra.projectconnecttoastmasters.MapsActivity" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Android Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.prateekchachra.projectconnecttoastmasters">        

        <!--
             The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
             Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
             location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
        -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <permission android:name="com.example.prateekchachra.projectconnecttoastmasters.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">        

            <!--
                 The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
                 (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
                 Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
                 You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
                 sign the APK for publishing.
                 You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="ID" />        

            <activity
                android:name=".MapsActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">        

            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".Events"
                android:label="Events List">
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".FindSlots"
                android:label="Find Slots">
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".MapScreen"
                android:label="Map Main">
    </activity>
            <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
                android:label="Splash Screen">        

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />        

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>        


        </application>        

    </manifest>
```

Logcat Output:

05-24 03:59:40.867 26851-26851/com.example.prateekchachra.projectconnecttoastmasters E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prateekchachra.projectconnecttoastmasters/com.example.prateekchachra.projectconnecttoastmasters.MapScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
                                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
                                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
                                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
                                                                                                           at com.example.prateekchachra.projectconnecttoastmasters.MapScreen.onCreate(MapScreen.java:34)
                                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
                                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
                                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
                                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
                                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
                                                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
                                                                                                           at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
                                                                                                           at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
                                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4727)
                                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
                                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281) 
                                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881) 
                                                                                                           at com.example.prateekchachra.projectconnecttoastmasters.MapScreen.onCreate(MapScreen.java:34) 
                                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122) 
                                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081) 
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
                                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
                                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
                                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
                                                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Can you show us your Log Trace when the application is crashing and Manifest also

Comment: <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="ID" />      
What is ID ?? I think this is the problem here place your api key here and also show us the log trace when the app is crashing

Comment: Its the private key, I have it. Its not the issue here, I'm debugging right now and will paste the log trace ASAP.

Comment: The debugger is taking forever to load, actually the rest of the activities work perfectly. It crashes as soon as map is about to be launched.

Comment: Well I can't help until you provide the Logcat output.
By the mean time read the following tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm

Comment: Got it, apparently you don't need to debug forever for that lol

Comment: android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
Replace with your Fragment package and fragment name like
android:name="com.example.prateekchachra.projectconnecttoastmasters.MapScreen"

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!

Comment: Like and Up-vote my Answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your android :name in  your XML file

```
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" 
Replace with your Fragment package and fragment name like 
android:name="com.example.prateekchachra.projectconnecttoastmasters.MapScreen"
```